# How to read this lambda x: f'{x:0>6}'

Tags: python

I am new to python, how to read f'{x:0>6}' in the following code

```
df[col].map(lambda x: f'{x:0>6}')
```

I found f meant [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). But I don't understand what the whole expression mean.

Comment: x is the variable and 0>6 is a formatting instruction passed to `x.__format__`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#formatspec

Comment: Python 3.6 introduced the f string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means right aligned front pad zeros for any value of x if x has less than 6 digits:

```py
s = [(lambda x: f'{x:0>6}')(num) for num  in [4, 45, 123456]]
print(s)
# ['000004', '000045', '123456']
```

`lambda` is a nameless function that is used mostly on fly: The  lambda expression is equivalents to

```py
def padd_zero(x):
    return f'{x:0>6}'

s = [padd_zero(num) for num  in [4, 45, 123456]]
print(s)
# ['000004', '000045', '123456']
```

In the example `df[col].map(abc)`. abc is applied to all values in col, just as we apply the functions to the list above.

See: [Strings Docs 3.6+](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#formatexamples)